# Web API 2.2 - ApiController to ODataController (changing Content Type after setting Formatter)

Tags: iframe, odata, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I have a Web API 2.2 controller that is under conversion to use OData v4. In the ApiController I am able to do this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, MyObject);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
return ResponseMessage(response);
```

Which sends back a Http Status Code of 201 - Created, with an object serialized as JSON in the body (default formatter for Web API 2.2), and a content-type of text/html.

The reason this works is the Request.CreateResponse() sets the formatter to JSON, and that persists despite my change to the content type directly afterwards. So the object is serialized as JSON, and the response is sent back with a content-type of text/html.

The reason I need this, is the existing front-end utilizes an iframe to perform an upload, and the response is then extracted from the iframe body to relay any information to the user. If the content-type was of application/json the browser would try to save it as a file. But as text/html, it simple gets injected into the iframe. Which we can rip out and deserialize into a javascript object.

Now trying to do the same breaks if using an ODataController, with the following error:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":{
      "message":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/html'.","type":"System.InvalidOperationException","stacktrace":"","internalexception":{
        "message":"A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...' matches the content type 'text/html'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataContentTypeException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.Core.MediaTypeUtils.GetFormatFromContentType(String contentTypeName, ODataPayloadKind[] supportedPayloadKinds, ODataMediaTypeResolver mediaTypeResolver, ODataMediaType& mediaType, Encoding& encoding, ODataPayloadKind& selectedPayloadKind)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.MediaTypeUtils.GetFormatFromContentType(String contentTypeHeader, ODataPayloadKind[] supportedPayloadKinds, ODataMediaTypeResolver mediaTypeResolver, ODataMediaType& mediaType, Encoding& encoding, ODataPayloadKind& selectedPayloadKind, String& batchBoundary)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageWriter.EnsureODataFormatAndContentType()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageWriter.SetHeaders(ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageWriter.SetOrVerifyHeaders(ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageWriter.WriteToOutput[TResult](ODataPayloadKind payloadKind, Action verifyHeaders, Func`2 writeFunc)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageWriter.CreateODataEntryWriter(IEdmNavigationSource navigationSource, IEdmEntityType entityType)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems the OData formatter works a bit differently. And while removing my content-type assignment line sends back the OData serialized properly, it does so with a content type of application/json, which the browser then tries to save to a file...

Any ideas on how I can get the ODataController to work like the ApiController? Am I going to have to create my own formatter to do this? Seems a bit silly considering the only thing I want to change is the returned content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got it working the way I wanted, more or less, by using OWIN and writing my own middleware.

Basically I wanted a way to force a content-type without having to write a specific oData formatter for each instance. So oData could continue to format whichever way it was told to, and I would just tell the browser to treat it as plain text (or whatever else I wanted it to be).

That way I could make a request through an iframe (normally to upload or download a file), and if an error occurred, the return would be plain text. Which Internet Explorer would then ignore (application/json or application/xml responses were seen as files, and always kicked off a download prompt). Most other browsers accepted application/json or application/xml just fine, but IE always wanted to download it as a file?!?!

My attempts at using the WebAPI pipeline to do this were less than successful, as it appears that MessageHandlers are actually hit prior to the oData serialization process as the responses make their way out the door.

But it looks like OWIN lets me work on the response after the oData serialization, which is really what I wanted. Below is the "proof-of-case" OWIN middleware class I threw together, it takes a specific querystring value and uses that to coerce the content-type of the response before it gets sent downstream.

It could use a little refinement, but for now it gets the job done (and it works for any request, I have side-by-side WebAPI and oData controllers, and both can use the querystring to coerce the content-type).

```
public class OWINCustomMiddleware : OwinMiddleware {

  public OWINCustomMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next): base(next) {
  }

  public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {

  //Check if a content-type coercion querystring token is present
    if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue) {
      NameValueCollection queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
      String coerce = queryString.Get("$coerce");
      if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(coerce)) {
      //Remove $coerce token so it doesn't impact future methods
        queryString.Remove("$coerce");
        context.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(queryString.ToString());
      //Append a header to the request, to be later used in Response Content-Type coercion
        context.Request.Headers.Add("coerce", new String[] { coerce });
      }
    }

    await Next.Invoke(context);

  //Coerce existing response content-type to value of coerce header (if present)
    if (context.Request.Headers != null) {
      if (context.Request.Headers["coerce"] != null) {
        Int32 index = context.Response.ContentType.IndexOf(';');
        if (index > 0) {
          context.Response.ContentType = context.Request.Headers["coerce"] + context.Response.ContentType.Substring(index, context.Response.ContentType.Length - index);
        } else {
          context.Response.ContentType = context.Request.Headers["coerce"];
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

If anyone knows of a way to do this directly using the WebAPI pipeline (without OWIN) I'd still like to know, so please post if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Call this in your startup/config code:

```
var odataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.AddRange(odataFormatters);
```

Comment: The unfortunately killed all the formatters (basically killing the standard APIController I have running side-by-side this new ODataController), and still didn't create an OData formatter that allows me serialize as JSON but respond with a text/html MediaTypeHeader. But I may be able to use it as a jumping point, let me see where I get.

Comment: I have the same setup (ApiControllers and ODataControllers living together). The trick (for me) was to call the OData config in the startup prior to the WebApi config. I don't have formatters in my api config, only routes; and after that I call 'app.UseWebApi(config)'. This uses the 'IAppBuilder app' in my Startup.cs (Owin-style).

Comment: I'm still a bit lost on this. Really I don't want OData to do anything differently, except return it's serialized data with a text/html MediaTypeHeaderValue. I literally want formatted xml or json, but I want the browser to see it as text/html instead of applicaiton/xml or application/json.

Comment: Can you post a sample project?